# Buttons repeats in select menu

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to do a footer with 5 fields. One of them would be a select button, but I don't know why I get two select buttons!!

This is my code:

```
<div class="ui-bar ui-grid-c" style="height:30px;width:100%;border-top:solid 2px black;">
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:55%;">
        <div class="ui-bar ui-grid-a" style="display:inline;">
            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:35%;text-align:left;">
                    <label for="mydate" style="margin-top:10px;font-size:10pt;"><b>Compare:</b></label></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:65%;text-align:left;margin-top:-10px;"><input name="CompareDate" id="mydate" style="height:35px;" type="date" data-role="datepicker" data-options='{"hideInput": true,"mode": "calbox", "useTodayButton": true}'></div></div></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:20%;text-align:left;margin-left:-5px;">
            <select name="select-choice" id="select-choice" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="notext" >
                <option></option>
                <option value="auto">Auto</option>
                <option value="mix">Mix</option>
                <option value="superpose">Superpose</option>
            </select></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c" style="width:12%;text-align:right;margin-left:2px;"> 
           <a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="arrow-l">-12 hours</a></div>
    <div class="ui-block-d" style="width:12%;text-align:left;margin-left:3px;">
           <a href="#" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="arrow-r">+12 hours</a></div>
</div><!-- Footer -->
```

Ans this is how it looks like:
[image]

As you can see I get one button without icon and another right below with the gear icon.Both display same select menu.

Code in: http://jsfiddle.net/a7pBW/6/

Anyone has any idea why this is happening?? I'm sure is a stupid thing but I'm not able to see it!!

Thank you very much!!

UPDATE:

I found out it has something to with the data-native-menu option, but I don't know how to solve it yet.

I think is a JQuery bug because when I run the code with Fire Bug I can see how when you put the select with the icon internally in HTML I can find two references to the button, this is why its repeated. I still don't know how to solve it, I have just worked in positioning both in the same exact position so you can´t see there are two buttons instead of one, but I will keep working as this is not a good way!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a css issue. Use no-repeat option in your button background image css.

Comment: I'm trying to add this to my css file but doesn't work:  select{
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

Comment: Try to use this property with "#select-choice" as you are using id of select box. Kindly ask if it is not working.

Comment: I have tried that, as well as .select-choice or body, or div, but nothing is working! Do you have any other idea?? Thank you so much!

Comment: It will be better if you can show your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ so that I can give you proper explanation.

Comment: It looks like the web is not working right now. But I will post it as soon as it works and post a comment here so you know is online!! I really apreciate your answers!! thank you very much!

Comment: It is a point to remember that It is always better to use css classes instead of using inline css. :)

Comment: Hi, there is something wrong with the class "ui-block-b" you used in the container div of select element. I removed this class and it worked, but some images were not shown. So if you can manage this class. You will be done that issue.

Comment: I tried taking out the ui-block-b class and is still the same. I have also tried to take out the select from the footer and display it alone and it keeps comming twice!!Thank you so much for your time!